# what would be the equivalent tool to this in blender

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, selection-tools, proportional-editing

https://help.maxon.net/us/index.html#TOOLMAGNET
it acts like a sculpting brush in blender but u can select faces and only affect them it also has fall off

heres a showcase of the tool compared to soft selection aka proportional editing
https://youtu.be/JArOaI8dC8M?t=791

Answer (score -1):

You can use the "proportional editing" hiding all the part of the mesh (H) you don't want to move.

here the process:

[image]